# File.WriteAllText not working when first call is made in program

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io

I am facing a very strange issue with writing a Text file using File.WritelAllText C# method. This method doesn't write the file in the User's Application directory (`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`), when I execute the program for first time.

I am calling this method in the **Navigate2** method of file **IEToolbarEngine.cs** of IE toolbar application posted on code project - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29215/Pretty-IE-Toolbar-in-C

There is no error either which makes it difficult to identify what is wrong.

Here is the method

```
internal void Navigate2 (string url)
        {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (url)) return;
                object val = null;
                object objURL = url;
                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\text.htm";

                File.WriteAllText(path, System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());



                objURL = path;
                Explorer.Navigate2(ref objURL, ref val, ref val, ref val, ref val);

        }
```

Could anyone please explain this unexpected behavior?

Comment: There is no exception in the code while executing. Nothing is caught in catch block.

Comment: Removed catch block from the method! but still the problem continues.

Comment: And any other similar "ignore errors" catch blocks in callers (and their callers recursively)?

Comment: No. I debug the application line by line without error. I believe that if there is any error VS2010 will report. The program exit gracefully.

Comment: Could it be related with security? There are some unmanaged code (COM) dlls used in the application.

Comment: What does [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) show you about file operations on that file?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this tool. I figured out that on the first call of File.WriteAllText the file is created in temporary directory "C:\Users\user_xyz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized" but the file is not copied at specified path (which is strange). In subsequent call, file does get copied in the specified path. Any idea?

Comment: You're application is running inside one (or more) of IE's worker processes. These run at reduced elevation "low". At this level the process is very limited to where it can access files.

Comment: Make sense. Internet Explorer 7 in Vista and Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7 runs in "Protected Mode". To add to what you have said in your comment, please have a look at the first answer to this post - http://goo.gl/r44zK6 . But if the security (low elevated) is the case, how come program able to write the file in this location in subsequent calls?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid (I don't write IE addins).